# How to store and load boolean array in Shared Preference in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-preferences

friends can anybody to check this code for storing boolean array in shared preference ,The code is not working

```
  toggleButtonArray=new Boolean[47];

    for(int j=0;j<47;j++)
    {
        toggleButtonArray[j]=true;
    }
    SharedPreferences prefs_tbutton = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TogglePreference", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs_tbutton.edit();  
    editor.putInt("tbPreferenceArray" +"_size", toggleButtonArray.length); 

    for(int i=0;i<toggleButtonArray.length;i++)
    {
        editor.putBoolean("tbPreferenceArray" + "_" + i, toggleButtonArray[i]);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "preference saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    editor.commit();
```

Code to load the boolean array is

```
public Boolean[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  


    SharedPreferences prefs_tbutton = mContext.getSharedPreferences("TogglePreference", 0);  
    int size = prefs_tbutton.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    Boolean array[] = new Boolean[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs_tbutton.getBoolean(arrayName + "_" + i, false);  
    Log.e("ARRAY LOADING","SEEKING");

    return array;  
}
```

Let me know what is the errorin this code please..............

code ,loadArray

```
public class TimerService extends Service {


public  Boolean[] tbPreferenceArray;

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                tbPreferenceArray=loadArray("tbPreferenceArray",getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I would suggest you to serialize it to json

Comment: Use Context.MODE_PRIVATE instead of 0 in sharedprefernce and remove getApplicationContext().

Comment: What values do your `size` and `arrayName` have?

Comment: @George : size =47,and arrayName is toggleButtonArray[]

Comment: @ A.S Can u give an example

Comment: Show us how you invoke the `loadArray()` method (post the code). Do you get any errors? Is your logcat outputting the `Log.e("ARRAY LOADING","SEEKING");` statement?

Comment: @George D : I hv updated the code ,plz check.I dont get any errors, this statement  is working properly Log.e("ARRAY LOADING","SEEKING");

Comment: @George : Can you show me another example for storing and retriving boolean array in  Shared preferences ??

Comment: Are you sure the array isn't filled with boolean values? Cal you print out the 'tbPreferenceArray'? Does your service start? Do you invoke the 'start' method on the 'new Thread();'

Comment: I tested your code and it ran fine for me, the values loaded were all true.

Comment: @GeorgeD: Thanx george its working now

Comment: @samgk : Thanx for the support, It s working now